# Visual studio code - Intellisense across JS modules

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, editor, intellisense, visual-studio-code

In the new VS Code editor, let's say I have two javascript files `foo.js` and `bar.js` with `bar.js` containing this:

```
module.exports.sayBar = function () {
    console.log('bar')
}
```

In `foo.js`, if I type `require('./bar').` and hit `ctrl+space` to activate intellisense, it doesn't detect that one of the methods in the module is `sayBar()` (I already have the default `jsconfig.json` file that VS Code asks if you want to generate).

Is there some other configuration step to activate intellisense for other JS files that I've written? I really liked that feature for C++ projects in VS Express and it would cause VS Code to blow Atom completely out of the water IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work for CommonJS modules. In your example it should be:

```
exports.sayBar = function() {
  console.log('bar');
};
```

or

```
module.exports = {
  sayBar: function() {
    console.log('bar');
  }
};
```

[image]